# Как выронить меню по центру блока?

Tags: css

Перечитал варианты, но почему-то они не работают на конкретном сайте. Как сделать меню по центру страницы корректно? Имеется ввиду `margin 0 auto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для того что бы сработал margin 0 auto - требуется что бы елемент был блочным(либо в css display: block), с конкретно заданной шириной

update после приложения ссылки

задайте ul text-align: center и все отцентрируется

Comment: display: block стоит, но возможно не тот порядок.

Comment: @Agestor, обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю! Действительно не хватало ul text-align: center.

Comment: @Agestor, тогда отмечайте ответ верным) не за что)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.center {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
}
#red {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div id="red"></div>
</div>
```

Рекомендую использовать также данный сервис http://howtocenterincss.com

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!